# Can advertisers on Stack Overflow / Stack Exchange target a specific single user?

Tags: support, advertising

Can advertisers on Stack Overflow or Stack Exchange target a **specific single user**?

Comment: Probably not *intentionally*; what use would you see for this?

Comment: @Shog9 just wanted to know.

Comment: Also... do you mean "I want this ad to go to HIM specifically, and whoever else might be interested", or "I want this ad to go to him, only him, and no one but him?" might change the answer

Comment: @Patrice _"him, only him and no one but him"_.

Comment: @jstreet so, even if I am not a Stack Overflow employee and have no visibility in if this is doable or not, I don't see the reasoning into why stack would offer that, and why it would appeal to advertisers. By definition ads are meant to target a LOT of people. Feels like breaking this to offer a targeted ad to only one person.... Do you think you have been targeted by a particular ad? :p

Comment: @Patrice I just want to know.

Comment: @jstreet then, until we have an actual Stack employee showing up and giving the real answer, we are left with the one that makes sense: Ads are not for this, so logically, this shouldn't be offered by Stack to advertisers. Even if it was I don't see any advertisers going for an offer like that.

Comment: I'd like to only target Jon Skeet.

Comment: Roberrrt, I targeted Jon Skeet already.

Comment: "Wake up, Neo…"

Answer (score 35, accepted):

***Nope.***

The reasons mentioned in the comments apply, for sure. If an advertiser asked us to target a specific user, I'd first remind them that Stack Overflow users tend to be particularly awareof and averse to tracking, and targeting a specific user will definitely creep them out. Immediately after that (important) point, I will emphasize that it will be a waste of time, energy, and money to specifically target *one* user. Finally, I'd tell them that we do not offer that kind of targeting, and don't have plans to do so in the future. Alternative scenario: just start with that last bit and skip the rest. ;-)

Comment: Thanks for confirming my hypothesis! (although to be fair I saw no other answer than that one because... well... logic)

Comment: Stack Overflow: where the users you track might be tracking you back!

Comment: Later, jon skeet sees jon skeet ads

Comment: 'Nope'. In other words, only Jon Skeet can create an SO ad that specifically targets him.

Comment: I turn on AdBlock because I don't want targeted ads!